# Solve this system of polynomial equations.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations

**Question**

Solve
$\begin{cases}
6x-y-z=51\\
x^2+y^2+z^2=2010
\end{cases}$
for positive integers $x,y,z$.

**Answer**

$(x,y,z)=(17,40,11)$ or $(17,11,40)$.

**My problem**

Obviously $y+z=6x-51$ and $y^2+z^2=2010-x^2$, and then I got stuck here. I don’t know how to continue.

You don’t have to show me the complete solution. Just a hint will be fine.

Comment: I agree that you may genuinely have no idea how to solve the problem but in order to maintain this site has a repository of quality mathematical knowledge, you should read this: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @SarGe I see. I will try to add some of my thoughts (though may be useless). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is correct.

The inequality $$2y^2+2z^2\geq (y+z)^2$$

gives $$-38x^2+612x+1419\geq 0$$ which simplifies to

$$-x^2+16x+38>0$$ where $16$ and $38$ comes from rounding up $612\over38$ and $1419\over 38$

Complete the square and you get $(x-8)^2<102$ and therefore $x<18$.

From the first equation we know $x\geq9$ and from the second equation mod $4$ we two one of $x,y,z$ are odd, one is even. If $x$ is the even one then the first equation won't hold so $x$ is odd and can only be $11,13,15,17$.

Four cases shouldn't be hard to check manually.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Replace the value of $z$
$$x^2+y^2+(6x-y-51)^2=2010$$ which is a quadratic equation in $x$

As $x$ is integer, the discriminant must be perfect square

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the equation $y+z=6x-51$ as $(1)$ and $y^2+z^2=2010-x^2$ as $(2)$. Then $(1)^2 - (2)$ gives:

$$y^2+2yz+z^2 - (y^2+z^2) = (6x-51)^2 - 2010 + x^2$$
$$\Rightarrow 2yz = 36x^2-612x+2601 - 2010 +x^2$$
$$\Rightarrow 2yz = 37x^2-612x+591$$
$$\Rightarrow 37x^2-612x+(591 - 2yz)=0$$

Since $yz$ are positive, then the value of $x$ must lie between the roots of $37x^2-612x+(591 - 2(1)(1)) = 0$ or $37x^2-612x+589 = 0$.  Dividing by $37$ and rounding up gives $x^2-17x-16$, and since $x$ is positive, $0 < x < 17$.

The discriminant $(-612)^2 - 4(37)(591-2yz) = 296yz+287076 = 4(74yz + 71769)$ also must be a perfect square.

$71769 \equiv 26 \pmod {37}$. $26$ is a quadratic residue modulo $37$ so there is a solution.

Comment: Fixed. I originally divided by $37$, so the $17$ instead of $37$ is just a typo.